# Listbox throwing exceptions when its pressed

Tags: c#, winforms

So when I press the space in the listbox it gives this error

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\tamov\Downloads\PEOROX EWEEQWWW\scripts\

This is my code

```
string script = File.ReadAllText(string.Format("./scripts/{0}", this.listBox1.SelectedItem));
bool flag = this.listBox1.SelectedItem != null;
bool flag2 = flag;
if (flag2)
{
  this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetText", new object[]
  {
    script
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm going with the path isn't valid, or you don't have permission to that folder.

Comment: Is that what the full file path is supposed to be?  Isnt it missing the file name portion?

Comment: Well it works when an item in the listbox is selected @ŇɏssaPøngjǣrdenlarp

Comment: If nothing is selected, then SelectedItem is nothing.  Check for that.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not select anything, your SelectedItem can be null as rightly pointed out in the comments.

The posted code seems to be accessing the SelectedItem before it even checked if it is null.

Pull it inside the if condition to make sure it is executed only when SelectedItem is not null.

```
bool flag = this.listBox1.SelectedItem != null;
bool flag2 = flag;
if (flag2)
{
  string script = File.ReadAllText(string.Format("./scripts/{0}", this.listBox1.SelectedItem));
  this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetText", new object[]
  {
    script
  });
}
```

OR, if you need the variable `script` elsewhere outside the `if`-condition, declare it outside where you did originally but set it inside the `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect to see that written more like this:

```
if (this.listBox1.SelectedIndex != -1)
{
    string script = File.ReadAllText(string.Format("./scripts/{0}", this.listBox1.SelectedItem));
    this.webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("SetText", new object[] { script });
}
```